# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss

I am using javax validation in my application. I have added the following dependencies in the project pom file.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.logmanager</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-logmanager</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
       <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
       <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

When i am running the application i am getting the following exception.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.logging.LoggerFactory.make(LoggerFactory.java:28)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version.<clinit>(Version.java:27)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.<clinit>(ConfigurationImpl.java:63)
        at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.createGenericConfiguration(HibernateValidator.java:41)
        at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:269)
        at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:111)
```

I have tried this with and without jboss logging pkgs.

Please lets me know what is error i am making and how it can be resolved.

Comment: Can this link help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/15414902/2086065 Just try to find out all classes whose name is org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger.

Comment: Are you running in JBoss AS?

Comment: You might have 2 different versions of the same jar on your classpath, do a `mvn dependency:tree` and search the results for multiple versions of `jboss-common` or `jbossall-client`

Comment: What container are you running in?